# Python Google Sheets APIv4: Multiprocessing and Multithreading at the same time

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, google-sheets-api

I can get multiprocessing and multithreading to work with google sheets APIv4 independently, but I can't get them to work together.

Multiprocessing (this works):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import threading
import pandas

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.core = 10
        self.b()

    def b(self):
        p = Pool(self.core)
        p.map(multicore, range(10))

def multicore(*args):
    thread = 0
    if thread == 1:
        thread_list = []
        for i in range(10):
            thread = threading.Thread(target=output_function, args=(i,))
            thread_list.append(thread)
            thread.start()
    else:
        output_function(*args)

def output_function(*args):
    x = args[0]

    print(x * x)
    g.build_service()

    g.export_df(g.test_API_key, ['output!A' + str(x + 1)], [pandas.DataFrame([[x * x]])], 'n')
```

Multithreading (this also works):

```
def just_threading():
    thread = 1
    if thread == 1:
        thread_list = []
        for i in range(10):
            thread = threading.Thread(target=output_function, args=(i,))
            thread_list.append(thread)
            thread.start()

def output_function(*args):
    x = args[0]

    print(x * x)
    g.build_service()

    g.export_df(g.test_API_key, ['output!A' + str(x + 1)], [pandas.DataFrame([[x * x]])], 'n')
```

But when I combine them by setting `thread = 1` for the first example, I get absolutely no output to google sheets (`print(x*x)` still works).

What's funny is that if I take away `g.build_service()`, it will output a few lines until it runs into Thread safety issues outlined here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/thread_safety with error `ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2273)`. So rebuilding the service does matter, but I see no output to sheets!

Comment: You need to wait for the threads to finish in either case. e.g. `[t.join() for t in thread_list]`

Comment: @stacksonstacks i don't understand. I thought the join() function was used for things that are dependent on each other. The multithreading example works perfectly fine without it. Can you explain why I need it?

Comment: No that's not what it's for. `join()` will block the current thread until the other is complete, otherwise the main thread i.e your program will exit even if its child threads aren't done. Use some google-fu for a more in depth explanation

Comment: @stacksonstacks. wow that did it. Looks like the program finished before the threads could output. Put it in the answer and I will give you the 100 points. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: i gotta wait 3 hours to reward the bounty

Comment: updated thread safety link: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/thread_safety.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the threads to finish their work, otherwise the main thread will exit before they complete.

After you've launched the threads, run:

```
for t in thread_list:
    t.join()
```